# How do I access a data value in a dictionary in the html template

Tags: html, django, dictionary, templates, jinja2

I'm passing a dictionary in the context in my views.py to my html template. How do I know access a value in the template based on a particular key. For instance I'd wanna do something like {{ dictionary.keyname.value }} but I don't know the correct syntax and for some reason I can't seem to find the documentation.

I want to achieve the same effect as this without having to use a for loop:

```
     <b>Calories</b>
     {% for key, value in output.items %}
        {% if key == "calories" %}
          {{ value }}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want `{{ output.calories }}`.